# SQL running in loop?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having problems with a SQL query, it just seems to keep running and never complete.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS rental_details;
CREATE VIEW rental_details AS
SELECT a.rental_id, a.rental_date, a.return_date,
    b.film_id, b.store_id, 
    c.first_name AS staff_name, 
    d.first_name || ' ' || d.last_name AS customer_name,
    e.title, e.rental_duration, e.rental_rate, e.length, e.replacement_cost, e.rating,
    g.name AS category_name,
    h.total_amount AS amount_paid
FROM rental AS a 
JOIN inventory AS b ON b.inventory_id = a.inventory_id 
JOIN staff AS c ON c.staff_id = a.staff_id
JOIN customer AS d ON d.customer_id = a.customer_id
JOIN film AS e ON e.film_id = b.film_id 
JOIN film_category AS f ON f.film_id = e.film_id 
JOIN category AS g ON g.category_id = f. category_id
LEFT JOIN (select rental_id, sum(amount) as total_amount 
from payment 
group by rental_id) as h ON a.customer_id = d.customer_id
```

Comment: Is it when you are creating the view that it runs for ever, or when you execute the view?  If it is when executing the view, then you need to show the query plan.

Comment: The problem may be that on the left join you aren't using h alias to establish the relationship (h.rental_id).

Comment: I think @PepeNO is right: because you aren't actually joining on any fields of the subquery, ALL of them, every last grouped row, will be joined to every row in the rest of your query. That's going to be one big record set.

Answer (score 0):

Using common sense, this coul be a correction:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS rental_details;
CREATE VIEW rental_details AS
SELECT a.rental_id, a.rental_date, a.return_date,
    b.film_id, b.store_id, 
    c.first_name AS staff_name, 
    d.first_name || ' ' || d.last_name AS customer_name,
    e.title, e.rental_duration, e.rental_rate, e.length, e.replacement_cost, e.rating,
    g.name AS category_name,
    h.total_amount AS amount_paid
FROM rental AS a 
JOIN inventory AS b ON b.inventory_id = a.inventory_id 
JOIN staff AS c ON c.staff_id = a.staff_id
JOIN customer AS d ON d.customer_id = a.customer_id
JOIN film AS e ON e.film_id = b.film_id 
JOIN film_category AS f ON f.film_id = e.film_id 
JOIN category AS g ON g.category_id = f. category_id
LEFT JOIN (select rental_id, sum(amount) as total_amount 
from payment 
group by rental_id) as h ON h.rental_id = a.rental_id
```